# What does the ListIterator object point to immediately after creation?

Tags: java, null, listiterator

When i first create an object of ListIterator and assign it to a given (pre-existing) ArrayList, will the object point to the first node of the list, or does it(in the code below, 'current') initially point to NULL?

```
ArrayList<Integer> _list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
_list.add(15);
_list.add(20);
ListIterator current = _list.listIterator();
```

Comment: ListIterators don't "point to" elements. See the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

Comment: "Hi, I haven't read the documentation. Can you read it to me?"

Answer (score 1):

As per javadoc

> A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies
>   between the element that would be returned by a call to previous() and
>   the element that would be returned by a call to next().

[javadoc link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)